# Delay in navigation while using SWRevealViewController in Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using `SWRevealViewController` in Objective-C for drawing side navigation menu. It works fine on real device, but when I test the application in simulator, transitions among the screens from side menu are very slow. It takes more than 10 seconds to go to another screen from navigation menu. Has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: Can you make sure you haven't turned the slow transition on in the simulator? You can toggle it using cmd+t.

Comment: yes, it is turned off already. Only the controllers which are being called from side menu are loaded with delay. Rest of them are loading fine